# How to sort HashSet by HashCode()

Tags: sorting, hashcode

```
HashSet<Employee> hs= new HashSet<Employee>();
    Employee e1 = new Employee("Tatha",20,6000);
    Employee e2 = new Employee("Amar",30,9000);
    Employee e3 = new Employee("Aziz",25,15000);
    Employee e4 = new Employee("Tatha",20,6000);

    hs.add(e1);
    hs.add(e2);
    hs.add(e3);
    hs.add(e4);
```

how to sort by EmpID? in hashCode() method

Comment: A HashSet is a set - it is unordered. You could .ToLIst() the values and order the list. There is no EmpID visible in your code. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question.